# $\{a_1 - a_0, \dots, a_n - a_0\}$ is linearly indepedent if $\{a_0, \dots, a_n\}$ is geometrically independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-topology

Let's work in the vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$

Geometrical independence of $\{\overline{a_1}, \dots, \overline{a_n}\}$ is defined as:

If $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i \overline{a_i} = 0$ then $t_0 = t_1 = t_2 = \dots = t_n = 0$.

---

Attempt: If $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i(\overline{a_i} - \overline{a_0}) = 0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \overline{a_i} - \overline{a_0}\sum_{i=1}^n t_i = 0$.  Then clearly $\{t_i' = t_i / (\sum_{i=1}^n t_i) : i = 1, \dots, n\} \cup \{t_0'=-1\}$ is such that $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i' = 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i' \overline{a_i} = 0$.  Thus $t_i' = 0 \ \forall i$, but this does not work because we assumed $t_i' = -1$.

This from the first page of Munkre's *Intro. to Algebraica Topology*.

Comment: How is the other implication proven?

Comment: @user402543 make a question on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n t_i(a_i - a_0) = \sum_{i=1}^n t_ia_i - \sum_{i=1}^n t_ia_0 = (-t_1 -t_2 - \ldots - t_n)a_0  + t_1 a_1 + \ldots + t_na_n$$

Now notice that $$(-t_1 -t_2 - \ldots - t_n) + t_1 + \ldots + t_n = 0$$ so by geometrical independence of the set $\{a_0, \ldots, a_n\}$ we conclude:

$$-t_1 -t_2 - \ldots - t_n = 0$$
$$t_1 = 0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$t_n = 0$$

In particular $t_1 = t_2 = \ldots = t_n = 0$, so $\{a_1 - a_0, \ldots, a_n - a_0\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: How is the other implication proven?